# Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, phpmyadmin

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`incidencias`.`categories`, CONSTRAINT `categories_project_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`project_id`) REFERENCES `projects` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `categories` (`name`, `descripcion`, `project_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Categoría A1, , 1, 2022-08-10 10:20:04, 2022-08-10 10:20:04))

Este error me sale al insertar los datos en el seeder de category, comento el seeder y se me insertan los datos y todo bien pero por alguna razón que desconozco al descomentarlo y volver hacer la migración de las tablas con los datos me sale este error, las tablas las tengo de la siguiente forma

TABLA USER

```
    public function up()
    {
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();

        $table->string('password')->default('123456789');

        $table->smallInteger('role')->default(2);

        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
      });
    }

   /**
   * Reverse the migrations.
   *
   * @return void
   */
   public function down()
   {
   Schema::dropIfExists('users');
   }
 }
```

LA TABLA DE INCIDENTS

```
     class CreateIncidentsTable extends Migration{
    
    /**
    * Run the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
    */

    public function up()
    {
    Schema::create('incidents', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('descripcion');
        $table->string('severity',1);

        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');

        $table->integer('level_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('level_id')->references('id')->on('levels');

        $table->integer('client_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('users');

        $table->integer('support_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('support_id')->references('id')->on('users');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
  }

  /**
  * Reverse the migrations.
  *
  * @return void
  */
  public function down()
  {
    Schema::dropIfExists('incidents');
  }
 }
```

LA TABLA DE LEVELS

```
 Schema::create('levels', function (Blueprint $table) {
         $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');

        $table->integer('project_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('project_id')->references('id')->on('projects');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

LA TABLA DE CATEGORIAS

```
 Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('descripcion');

        $table->integer('project_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('project_id')->references('id')->on('projects');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

En categoriasseeder tengo este pedazo de codigo que es el cual si lo comento toda la base de datos funciona correctamente,

```
     'name'=>'Categoría A1',
        'project_id'=>1
    ]);
```

En projectstableseeder tengo el siguiente codigo

```
 Project::create([
        'name'=> 'Proyecto Clínica Casanova ',
        'descripcion'=>'El proyecto Clínica Casanova consiste en desarrollar un sitio 
    web basico de la clinica casanova'
    ]);
```

Entonces no se donde esta el error, porque me nombra la tabla incidencias que no existe en la base de datos

Esta es la estructura que queda de la base de datos, en el cual si inserto en la tabla category desde el phpmyadmin me sale el mismo error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la relación entre tablas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La inserción que falla crearía un registro huérfano con respecto a otra tabla relacionada, de ahí el error. Verifica con qué tabla está relacionada la tabla de inserción y verifica que en dicha tabla exista una fila con el valor que intentas insertar. Por lo general, este tipo de situaciones es mejor resolverlas de forma automática, a nivel de la base de datos, definiendo disparadores (TRIGGER) que se encarguen de mantener la integridad referencial.

Comment: Pero no se supone que esta cogiendo los datos de el archivo CategorySeeder?

Comment: Programar no es *suponer*, es controlar, verificar, encapsular, etc, no estás en el campo de la especulación así que no supongas nada. Tenemos un error concreto y más arriba te expliqué el motivo. El insert crearía en `categories` una fila que tendría registros huérfanos (no existen en la tabla relacionada)  y tienes que verificar eso, o controlarlo. Por lo general esto no se resuelve por programación en el lenguaje que sea, sino a nivel de base de datos, definiendo disparadores o funciones que controlen eso, ¿por qué? Porque a la base de datos se puede apuntar desde ...

Comment: ... múltiples contextos. Supongamos que hay una página web, una aplicación escrita en Java, otra escrita en Phyton, otra aplicación para móviles, etc, todas ellas apuntando a la misma base de datos. Si decides controlar este tipo de cosas desde el código de la aplicación, tendrás que programar cada vez estos controles, mientras que si garantizas esa integridad desde la misma base de datos, no tendrás que preocuparte luego de repetir una y otra vez este código de control desde los diferentes contextos. Aparte de los riesgos de error que corres haciendo fuera de la BD algo que debes hacer dentro

Comment: a nivel de BBDD, tengo poco conocimiento

Comment: Entiendo. He comentado lo anterior con la intención de abrir una perspectiva nueva. Considera que las BD están pensadas como un entorno completo desde el cual puedes manejar tus datos, independientemente del lugar desde el que se acceda a ellos (múltiples aplicaciones, lenguajes, contextos...), por tanto, conviene profundizar en el conocimiento de BD, porque te permitirá simplificar y centralizar muchas cosas. En cuanto al error concreto que tienes aquí, revisa con qué tabla se relaciona `categories` y verifica que en esa tabla relacionada el valor exista.

Comment: pude observar lo que intentaste hacer en phpmyadmin y estoy casi seguro que el error esta relacionado al uso de claves foraneas en tu estructura de base de datos.

Comment: si en phpmyadmin si me lo crea todas las relaciones con los datos pero al hacer un migrate:refresh --seed me salta el error y por mas que miro estoy en pesca total

Comment: ha y creo que la tabla se llama `incidents` no `incidencias` tambien te recomiendo no usar el opcache en desarrollo ....

Comment: si es que esta relacionada con la tablas incidents, mas arriba puse  como quedan relacionadas

Comment: puedes indicar en que linea de tu codigo php ocurre ??? estoy casi seguro que el error ocurre en un insert o un update que no estas mostrandonos ...

Comment: Ya lo corregí, el fallo estaba en la llamada de los seeders, que primero se tenia que ejecutar el de projects y luego el de categorias

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda a los dos